# Zabbix server not running

Tags: linux, server, redhat, zabbix

I just installed Zabbix 5.0 LTS (The Latest verion of Zabbix) on RHEL-8 OS. On logging in the Zabbix front end, I gett a message saying "Zabbix server is not working". & bar below says:"Zabbix server not working.Information delayed may not be current".Kindly provide help?

Edit:My server port is 10051.

On entering "service zabbix start", I get output:

```
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl start zabbix.service
Failed to start zabbix.service:Unit zabbix.service not found.
```

& on entering "systemctl restart zabbix-server zabbix-agent httpd php-fpm", I get:

```
Job for zabbix-server.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status zabbix-server.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

Output of "journalctl -xe":

```
RHEL8 platform-python[5746]: SELinux is preventing zabbix_server from using the dac_override capability.
*** Plugin dac_overrride (91.4 confidence) suggests ************************

If you want to help identify if domain needs this access or you have a file with the wrong permissions on your system
Then turn on full auditing to get path information about the offending file and generate the error again.
Do

Turn on full auditing
#auditctl -w /etc/shadow -p w
Try to recreate AVC.Then execute
#ausearch -m avc -ts recent
If you see PATH record check ownership/permissions on file, and fix it,
otherwise report as a bugzilla

*** Plugin catchall (9.59 confidence) suggests *************************

If you believe that zabbix_server should have the dac_override capability by default.
Then you should report this as a bug.
You can generate a local policy module to allow this access.
Do
allow this access for now by executing:
#ausearch -c 'zabbix_server' --raw | audit2allow -M my-zabbixserver
#semodule -X 300 -i my-zabbixserver.pp            

RHEL8 dbus-daemon[779]: [system] Activating service name='org.fedoraproject.Setroubleshootd' requested by ':1.40' (uid=0 pid=748 comm="/usr/sbin/sedispatch " label="sytem_u:system_r:auditd_t:s0") (using servicehelper)
```

On entering "systemctl status zabbix-server.service", I get output:

```
zabbix-server.service-Zabbix server: Loaded:....
                                     Active:....
                                     Process: 4959 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/zabbix_server -c $CONFILE (code=exited,status=1/FAILURE) 
RHEL8 systemd[1]:zabbix-server.service:Control process exited,code=exited status=1
RHEL8 systemd[1]:zabbix-server.service:Failed with result 'exit-code'.
RHEL8 systemd[1]:Failed to start Zabbix Server. What do I do now?
```

Comment: there aren't enough information to know what's happening. check the logfile for more informations, should be `/var/log/zabbix/zabbix_server.log`

Comment: I get output:                                                                                                                       -bash: /var/log/zabbix/zabbix_server.log: No such file or directory

Comment: and what's the output in `journalctl -xe` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved. I had to configure SELinux. Just go to "vim /etc/selinux/config" & change SELinux from "enforcing" to "permissive".After that,reboot the system & then Zabbix server will start working.

Answer (score 0):

You have seen that in this file /var/log/messages content about Zabbix. In this file you see a text like a bellow:

```
run sealert -l 84e0b04d-d0ad-4347-8317-22e74f6cd020
```

Do this command:

```
#sealert -l 84e0b04d-d0ad-4347-8317-22e74f6cd020
```

Then you see a verbose about this problem, to solve this you need to allow Zabbix in the environment. The command audit2allow does this.
link below: